# Deploy MERN app on render.com without Yarn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, mern, render.com

I'm trying to deploy only the server directory of my MERN app on render.com. I've found this link to the docs https://render.com/docs/deploy-node-express-app. The build command is using Yarn. However, my project is using NPM. What build command should I use? Also, what should the build script contain? I've only used Heroku before and do not remember having to run build command for the backend.

Comment: Did the answer solve Your problem? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The build command when it comes about `NPM` on `render.com` for `backend` *WEB SERVICE* should be

```
npm install
```

As we can read in `dashboard` render.com:

> Build Command
>
> This command runs in the root directory of your repository when a new
> version of your code is pushed, or when you deploy manually. It is
> typically a script that installs libraries, runs migrations, or
> compiles resources needed by your app.

[image]

---

For **frontend** STATIC SITE `React.js` should be

```
npm run build
```

As we can read in dashboard render.com

> Build Command
>
> This command runs in the root directory of your repository when a new
> version of your code is pushed, or when you deploy manually. It is
> typically a script that installs libraries, runs migrations, or
> compiles resources needed by your app.

[image]